# NULL dimension after using as.numeric function

Tags: r

I've a .csv file .I've read it with this command :

```
data<-read.csv(filename, header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

the data is look like this :

```
> data[1:5,1:6]
     X Group0 Group0.1 Group0.2 Group0.3 Group0.4
1   A      0        0        0        0        0
2   B      8       19       20       19        0
3   C      0        0        0        0        0
4   E      0        0        0        0        0
5   D      0        0        1        0        0
> 
make<-data[,-1]
>dim(make)
> 1000 500
make<-as.matrix(make)
dim(make)
>1000 500
make<- as.numeric(make)
>dim(make)
NULL
```

when I convert my data to numeric, it’s destroy. the dimension become `NULL`. sometime it's also happen when I convert it to **matrix** using `as.matrix` command.
could somebody help me what is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: `as.numeric` coerces a matrix to be a vector, and a vector doesnt have `dim` attributes, it has `length` instead`, so try `length(make)`. also this could be useful `data.frame(data[, 1], sapply(data[, -1], as.numeric))` if you want to convert number as numeric

Comment: Note that a matrix only can contain one type of data, if there is one character, then the entire matrix will be character, data.frames can contain different type of data, maybe you want to use a data.frame

Answer (score 4):

The `dim` function tell you the dimension of a matrix or a data frame, but doing the command `as.numeric` it is lost this structure of matrix to be a vector of type double.  Therefore the `dim` can not return the value of dimensions, because it is not longer a matrix.
To convert each column to numeric type of data you could use the following (untested) code:

```
make <-apply(make, 1, as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just save the dimensions of the matrix before using `as.numeric` and then assign those attributes back on the vector using `dim<-`. This will be very fast as it uses entirely vectorised primitive operations.

```
m <- matrix( sample(20) , 5 )

x <- dim(m)
#[1] 5 4

m <- as.numeric(m)
[1] 10  7 13 16 20 18  5 17  9  3  4  6 12  2 14 11 15  8 19  1

dim(m) <- x
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]   10   18    4   11
#[2,]    7    5    6   15
#[3,]   13   17   12    8
#[4,]   16    9    2   19
#[5,]   20    3   14    1
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could force to get x dimensions a vector

Comment: @Llopis yeah it's cool huh! Nice and simple reshaping. Of course Stephen is right - cut off the problem at source is probably even better.

Answer (score 4):

Importing data and converting the columns is a very common question, and Llopis answer is good.

I also think it sometimes better to cut these problems off at the pass: so import the columns in the right format.

so that would be something like..

```
df= read.csv(filename, header=T, sep=' ', colClasses=c('factor', rep('numeric',5)))
```

If you still want the numeric `data` matrix then that is just

```
data=df[,2:6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem and after I read elsewhere (http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/how-to-avoid-a-subset-of-a-matrix-to-become-a-column-vector-td2231926.html ), it suggests to add a drop=F to retain the "shape" of the original matrix. Just thought that this may be related since I stumbled on this page as well when searching along these lines:

```
>A=matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,1.5,1,1.5,2,2,2,2.3),4,3,byrow=T)

>A
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
    [1,]    0  0.0  1.0
    [2,]    0  0.0  1.5
    [3,]    1  1.5  2.0
    [4,]    2  2.0  2.3

> (A[A[,1]==1,-1])
[1] 1.5 2.0

> as.matrix(A[A[,1]==1,-1,drop=F])
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.5    2
> as.matrix(A[A[,1]==1,-1])
     [,1]
[1,]  1.5
[2,]  2.0
```

It can even be used in subsetting and prevent automatic reshaping into a column vector: e.g.

```
>B=matrix(c(0,0,1,0,0,2),2,3,byrow=T)
> B[B[,1]==1,-1]
[1] 1.5 2.0
> B[B[,1]==1,-1,drop=F]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1.5    2
```

** It doesn't work for as.numeric **